# How to set maximum limit for username with validation message in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

```js
<script>
export default {
  name: "Register",
  props: {
    msg: String,
  },
};
</script>
```

```css
<style scoped>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: system-ui;
}

.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<template>
  <div class="pop-up-mask">
    {{ msg }}
  <div class="input-wrapper"> 
          <div class="name-icon"></div>
            <input type="text" class="input-section" 
           placeholder="Enter your Name" :maxlength="max" v-model="text" />
         
        </div>
        </div>
        </template>
        
        
--------------in main.js--------------

new Vue({
 data: {
    max: 36,
    text: ''
  }
  render: h => h(App),

}).$mount('#app')
```

Mandatory (Text only 30 characters). If the user tries to enter more than 30 characters, the user get an error message : “You can enter 30 characters only.”. I tried placing a condition in the template like placeholder="Enter your Name" :maxlength="max" v-model="text". and main.js i placed a condition, but its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `watch`

Official documentation
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers

```js
<div class="pop-up-mask">
        {{ msg }}
        <div class="input-wrapper">
            <input
                type="text"
                class="input-section"
                placeholder="Enter your Name"
                :maxlength="max"
                v-model="msg"
            />
        </div>
    </div>
```

```js
<script>
  import LazyImageVue3 from 'lazy-image-vue3'

export default {
  name: 'App',
    data: () => ({
    max: 36,
    text: '',
    msg: '',
  }),
  components: {
    LazyImageVue3
  },
    watch: {
    msg(text) {
      console.log(text.length)
      if(text.length === 30) {
        this.msg = 'You can enter 30 characters only.'
        console.log('You can enter 30 characters only.')
        alert('You can enter 30 characters only.', text.length)
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried this, But its not limiting the user input to 30 characters.

Comment: Is there any other way of approaching in vue.js.   Tried the above code but no response

Comment: Answered above. Use `:disabled = '...'`

Answer (score 0):

While client side validation is nice and all, I recommend you instead validate the username on the server-side and return a statuscode `400` if the username is taken or too long. Your frontend can then detect when the submit request fails and display an error message.

Comment: Yes i understand that,But in Vuejs i wanted to know when  user tries to enter more than 30 characters, the user get an error message : “You can enter 30 characters only. Any idea on that

Comment: please need your suggestions for the above code

Answer (score 0):

add `:disabled = 'disable == 1'`

```js
<div class="pop-up-mask">
        {{ msg }}
<p v-if="this.show">{{ text2 }}</p>
        <div class="input-wrapper">
            <input 
                :disabled = 'disable == 1'
                type="text"
                class="input-section"
                placeholder="Enter your Name"
                :maxlength="max"
                v-model="msg"
            />
        </div>
    </div>
```

add `this.disable = 1`
`watch`

```js
watch: {
    msg(text) {
      console.log(text.length)
      if(text.length === 30) {
        this.show = true
        this.disable = 1
        this.msg = 'You can enter 30 characters only.'
        alert('You can enter 30 characters only.', text.length)
            }
        }
    }
```

add `disable: null`
`data`

```js
data: () => ({
    text2: 'You can enter 30 characters only.',    
    max: 36,
    text: '',
    msg: '',
    disable: null,      
  }),
```

You can also add conditional display `'You can enter 30 characters only.'`

**template**
`<p v-if="this.show">{{ text2 }}</p>`

**watch**
`this.show = true`

**data**
`show: false,`